# CheckedListBox VB.Net MultiExtended SelectionMode

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a `CheckedListBox` with a few items and I want to allow user to select more than one using arrows keys or mouse clicks combined with shift and ctrl keys so I set `SelectionMode` property to `MultiExtended`.

In design time it is not possible I get an error:

> value property is not valid.

and if I set it in runtime by doing:

```
clbEmployees.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple
```

I get an error too:

> CheckedListBox is not compatible with multiple selection.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported for the CheckedListBox.

However, I'm fairly sure that you could mimic that functionality in a ListView. Just look at the CheckBoxes and MultiSelect properties of the Listview. As far as I can tell from the documenation those are compatible.

Comment: Great idea! After searching documentation I have heard about checkedlistbox not supporting multiSimple, multi-Extend selection mode, only one selection. As far as I know now, multi selection is only supported by listbox. I have been searching information on how to do it with listview as you say, I mean, listview combined with checkboxes, and there is a nice example in this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes.aspx

I hope It can help other people.

Thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late, but I just put my solution here; Works perfect for me:
1- Just leave the CheckedListBox Selection mode as "ONE' in property sheet.
2- in your code, loop thru the checked item in your checked Box using the checked item property as following:
For each XX as 'DataTpe' in CheckedListBox.CheckedItems
      'Here you assign each checked item to wherever you want to direct to'
Next